# Project Euler: A (much) better way to solve problem #5?

Tags: haskell

You probably know about project Euler question 5: get the smallest number divisble by all numbers 1 to 20.

The logic I applied was "start with the first number greater than the largest of the list(20) and also divisible by it which is 40" and stepsize of 20 (largest number)

I did this using list comprehension but it's pretty lame.

```
pe5 = head    [x|x<-[40,60..],x`mod`3==0,x`mod`4==0,x`mod`6==0,x`mod`7==0,x`mod`8==0,x`mod`9==0,x`mod`11==0,x`mod`12==0,x`mod`13==0,x`mod`14==0,x`mod`15==0,x`mod`16==0,x`mod`17==0,x`mod`18==0,x`mod`19==0]
```

Can we do this better perhaps using zipWith and filter maybe?

Just to clarify, this is not a homework assignment. I'm doing this to wrap my brain around Haskell. (So far I'm losing!)

:Thanx all

I think this is a saner way (there may be thousand more better ways but this would suffice) to do it

```
listlcm'::(Integral a)=> [a] -> a
listlcm' [x] = x
listlcm' (x:xs) = lcm x (listlcm' xs)
```

Comment: Without algorithmic changes, just a shorter version `head [x | x <- [40,60..], all (\y -> x `rem` y == 0) [1..20]]`

Comment: If you want a much better algorithm you can think in terms of the `lcm`

Comment: @is7s i didn't ask for better algorithm but thanks for the clue and that all is as in "as" handler?

Comment: Btw, the title for this question is kinda non-descriptive (the "this" part could be clarified a bit more)

Comment: @hvr thanx, i will be more precise from now on

Comment: @Vasu I didn't understand the question in your comment. Please clarify more

Comment: @is7s copied from learnyou a haskell , there author calls using 'all' to keep the entire list "as patterns" is there any other function or name for usage of 'all' keyword                   capital :: String -> String
capital " " = " Empty string , whoops ! "
capital all@ ( x : xs ) = " The first letter of " ++ all ++ " is " ++ [ x

Comment: In the example you just gave, "all" is just a name it could be changed to any other name. You are just calling the list of characters (x:xs) as "all" so that you can refer to it by this name. However in the solution I gave `all` is a function. The `all` function basically checks that all the elements of a list satisfy a certain property. This property is identified by the boolean function of type (a -> Bool) given as an argument to `all`. In our case it was the lambda expression (\y -> x `rem` y == 0)

Comment: @is7s that helps .. no doubt now!

Comment: @hvr: Edited the title and added the appropriate tag.

Comment: You mentioned `zipWith`: something you could do is `zipwith mod (repeat x) [2..20]`, but there are better alternatives for the same strategy (see Henning Makholm's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do much better. For starters, rewrite to something like

```
head [x | x<-[40,60..], all (\y -> x`mod`y == 0) [2..20] ]
```

But what you really need here is not slicker Haskell, but a smarter algorithm. Hint: use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Your Haskell solution would then start with the standard sieve-of-Eratosthenes example.

Comment: Before seeing this, I had written `all (==0) $ zipWith mod (repeat x) [3..20]`, but I think yours is more concise.

Comment: Another easy optimization that cuts the runtime in half is to change `[2..20]` to `[11..19]`.

Answer (score 12):

In this particular case, you can get it for free using `foldl` and `lcm`:

```
euler = foldl lcm 2 [3..20]
```

This gives me 232792560 instantaneously.

Comment: foldl' is probably better (at least, for large inputs :))

Comment: Or even shorter: `foldl1 lcm [2..20]`

Answer (score 6):

Since the spoiler has already been posted, I thought I'd explain how it works.

The smallest number divisible by two numbers is also known as the *least common multiple* of those numbers. There is a function for calculating this in the Prelude.

```
λ> lcm 10 12
60
```

Now, to extend this to multiple numbers we exploit the following property

> *lcm(a<sub>1</sub>, ... a<sub>n</sub>) = lcm(lcm(a<sub>1</sub>, ... a<sub>n-1</sub>), a<sub>n</sub>)*

In Haskell, *f(f(... f(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>), ...), a<sub>n</sub>)* can be written `foldl1 f [a1, a2, ... an]`, so we can solve the problem with this simple one-liner:

```
λ> foldl1 lcm [1..20]
232792560
```

This finds the solution in a fraction of a second.

Comment: i know this is a bit too easy .. i know about the functionality of foldl (succesive function composition towards left of the list) i think my listlcm is easier (for a newbie) read my edit!

Comment: @Vasu: Perhaps for a beginner, but it's usually considered an anti-pattern to write your own recursion when one of the standard higher-order functions would do the job. Although there are cases where this can make code less readable, this is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a exercise in learning Haskell, I will only point out that there is a more efficient way to solve this problem mathematically but I will let you figure that out on your own. Instead, let's solve the problem in Haskell using your logic.

I simplified it a little bit:

```
head [x | x <- [20,40..], length( filter ( \y -> x `mod` y /= 0) [1..20]) == 0]
```

This creates a filter on the divisors list, and when its length is 0, it means all the divisors divide our x, so that must be our number. This reduces some of the clutter you had in your example. Note that this method is VERY slow; can you think of a better mathematical way to tackle this? Start looking at prime factorizations...